# How do I downgrade from 11.04 to 10.10?

Tags: 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

I installed Ubuntu 11.04, don't like it, can't get the classic desktop back, can't spend any more time on it, and want to get version 10 back.  Is there a way to downgrade from 11.04 to 10?

Comment: When you say 'can't get the classic desktop back', what do you mean, exactly? Ubuntu Classic is an option on the login screen, and will stick after subsequent reboots.